# Библиотека для candlestick графиков

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, посоветуйте пожалуйста библиотеку для candlestick графиков чтоб прям как на биржах(скрины приложил)[image: Bittrex][image: Yobit]

Comment: Библиотека plotly. Вот пример: https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/OpLmBe